# How can i change a numpy.ndarray to point format with curly brackets - Python 3.7

Tags: python, list, chart.js

I'm still new to Python, but developing a small Web App with Django, where I use Charts.js to generate a Scatterplot. 
The actual result I get is in the format of a `numpy.ndarray`.

Id like to convert it to the necessary "point format" like stated in the Charts.js documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html

Would be great if you have some simple ideas.

Current Datastructure:

```
result = 

    [[4.212000 8.954910]

 [4.467000 9.599410]

 [3.849000 9.235800]

 ...

[4.941000 7.130224]

[3.555000 4.513942]

[4.836000 4.868685]]
```

Desired Structure:

```
new_result = 

[{x: 4.212000, y: 8.954910},

{x: 4.467000, y: 9.599410},

{x: 3.849000, y: 9.235800},

...

{x: 4.941000, y: 7.130224},

{x: 3.555000, y: 4.513942},

{x: 4.836000, y: 4.868685}]
```

I know the question is probably pretty basic, but I got stuck for hours, looking for solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
new_result = [{'x': el[0], 'y': el[1]} for el in result]
```

Comment: No problems, list comprehension is a very common pattern in Python. It's very useful to know it well.

Answer (score 0):

try sth like:

```
def convert_array(arr):
    return [{'x':item[0],'y':item[1]} for item in arr]
```

use as:

```
converted_array = convert_array(numpy_array)
```